# T-SQL Comparing SQL DateTime Variables don't work. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

-- Works

```
DECLARE @MyDateFormatString NVARCHAR(MAX) = '2017-08-15 7:12:19 PM'
PRINT @MyDateFormatString
DECLARE @MyDateFormat DATETIME = '2017-08-15 7:12:19 PM'
PRINT @MyDateFormat
IF (CONVERT(DATETIME, @MyDateFormatString) = CONVERT(DATETIME, @MyDateFormat)) BEGIN PRINT 'YES!' END ELSE BEGIN PRINT 'NO' END
```

-- Does Not Work

```
IF (CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-08-15 7:12:19 PM') = CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Aug 15 2017  7:12PM')) BEGIN PRINT 'YES!' END ELSE BEGIN PRINT 'NO' END
```

-- WHY!!!

Comment: -- This Does Not Work

IF (CONVERT(DATETIME, @MyDateFormatString) = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @MyDateFormat))) BEGIN PRINT 'YES!' END ELSE BEGIN PRINT 'NO' END

Would really appreciate it if I could find some way to make the above work

Comment: Why would you expect it to work?   7:12:19<>7:12

Comment: xD Just didn't expect SQL to just throw away my seconds into the void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
IF (CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-08-15 7:12:19 PM') = CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Aug 15 2017  7:12PM')) BEGIN PRINT 'YES!' END ELSE BEGIN PRINT 'NO' END
```

to

```
IF (CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-08-15 7:12:19 PM') = CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Aug 15 2017  7:12:19 PM')) BEGIN PRINT 'YES!' END ELSE BEGIN PRINT 'NO' END
```

or

```
IF (CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-08-15 7:12 PM') = CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Aug 15 2017  7:12PM')) BEGIN PRINT 'YES!' END ELSE BEGIN PRINT 'NO' END
```

on your second query you're not comparing the seconds. On your first query you compare

> 2017-08-15 7:12 PM

to

> Aug 15 2017 7:12PM

Which is correct.

In the second one you compare

> 2017-08-15 7:12:19 PM

to

> Aug 15 2017  7:12PM

7:12:19 is not the same as 7:12. So change either format and it'll be correct.

EDIT:

To address your comment, if you want the DATETIME without seconds use SMALLDATETIME, it will work in your scenario. Have a look at this example using your original second query. BUT BE CAREFUL, it reduces the time format to hh:mm:00, so be wary of this:

```
IF (CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, '2017-08-15 7:12:19 PM') = CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Aug 15 2017  7:12PM')) BEGIN PRINT 'YES!' END ELSE BEGIN PRINT 'NO' END
```

Comment: Thank you. Here's why I did not spot that:

DECLARE DateTimeAutoConverted DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-08-15 7:12:19 PM')
DECLARE DateTimeAutoConvertedString NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), DateTimeAutoConverted)
PRINT DateTimeAutoConvertedString

SQL is kind enough to drop the seconds when auto converting the string I give it. Any way around that?

Comment: Try with DATETIME2 instead

Comment: @Shiasu-sama Look at my edit for you, and let me know if you have any questions. :-)

Comment: Hey Thanks.
Your workaround is better than mine; I ended up doing something like this
WHERE YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME, [DateOne])) = YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME, [DateTwo]))
AND MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME, [DateOne])) = MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME, [DateTwo]))
AND DAY(CONVERT(DATETIME, [DateOne])) = DAY(CONVERT(DATETIME, [DateTwo]))
which is much more tedious